# route for Devise sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The Devise wiki has instructions https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-appfor creating a sign_in form anywhere on a site. I wanted to put the sign_up form on the home page.

The sign_in form they recommend begins like this

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
```

Based on what that example and this output from rake routes

`new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new`

I started the sign_up form like this on my site home page

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => new_user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```

When I revved up the server and tried to sign up a user, I got this error

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

The one thing I notice is that `rake routes` shows a GET request for the new_user_registration, while my error message is showing a POST.  Not sure if that's significant.

```
Routes.rb



root :to => "home#index"
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

Comment: Can you paste your routes.rb file please?

Comment: @Jon updated OP with routes.rb. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that this

new_user_registration_path

is the wrong path. That goes to the "new" action

It should have been

user_registration_path

which goes to the "create" action